# How to give an app icon a notification badge without a number?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

On page 7 of Apple's Local and Push Notification Programming Guide there is a screenshot of the iPhone desktop, one of the application icons has a badge which does not contain a number - it is just plain red.

How is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: It must serve as an example. I've never seen it in an app, Apple's or a third party's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you want to do is not possible with the current notification API.
If you want to display the badge on your application icon, you must use the "badge" key in your APNS payload, and the value for this key must be an integer.

Even the local notification API has the same limitation, you can change the badge value with the applicationIconBadgeNumber property but, unfortunately, this property only accepts an integer.

It seems that only built-in apps (such as the phone app) can display a badge without number.

Comment: When does the phone app display a numberless badge?

Comment: Usually when you have new voicemails but visual voicemail is not available (when on roaming by example)

Comment: @GregK Does this stil hold true? I see applicationIconBadgeNumber only accepts integers but wasnt sure if anything else was added for making just a red dot possible to all apps