# New message badge on iOS app icon

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-cloud, badge

I need to display something like this to show there are new notifications for my app.

[image]

But I don't want to keep tracking the number of new notifications. Just a badge to show there are new ones, should be enough. So ideally, the badge is a red circle with "...".

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Badge on App Icon in Iphone App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790903/badge-on-app-icon-in-iphone-app)

Comment: So basically are you want to badge number via programmatically or are you want to display badge number on the app place of `...`.

Comment: Try to provide very big number like `999999999999` , the orb label may put `...` instead ! I didn't try that before , but It's a guess

Comment: I only want to show there are new messages. I don't need to show how many new messages, so I don't have the number for the badge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give an app icon a notification badge without a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841605/how-to-give-an-app-icon-a-notification-badge-without-a-number)

Comment: @Husam I was thinking the same. Tested, displays as `99...99` on the badge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I know you are using the IBM Push Notifications service on Bluemix there is an easy way to accomplish this. When sending a push notification using the IBM Push Notification service you can indicate a badge value as part of the optional payload:

> **iOS Badge** - For iOS devices, the number to display as the badge of the app icon. If this property is absent, the badge is not changed. To
>   remove the badge, set the value of this property to 0.

If you are sending the push notification through the Bluemix Push Dashboard, you can simply enter the badge value you want to be displayed once the notification is successfully received:

[image: BadgeIconOption]

If you are sending the push notification via Node.js, REST, etc you can add the badge value as an option parameter. Please take a look at the model provided in our REST API documentation to see the correct structure:

https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpushrestapidocs/#!/messages/post_apps_applicationId_messages

```
apns {
badge (integer, optional): The number to display as the badge of the application icon,
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should provide a number of "unread" notification in the badge. The Apple Human Interface Guidelines discourages using the badge for other purposes other than notifications.

You risk not having you app approved for sale in the AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

It should be number only. not possible to give string like "..." for your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you have to register for Local or Push Notifications first to show badge number on app icon.

Just in case you haven't done that here is the code for registering for Local Notifications

```
if (UIApplication.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:"))) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge], categories: nil))
        }
```

in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of `AppDelegate`

then try `UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 34` in `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller for testing

The badge value would be maintained by server if you are using Push Notifications